# What laws govern, empower, or limit indiscriminate accusatory TV Licensing mailings?

Tags: england-and-wales, extortion

[image]Anyone who has lived in the UK knows about postal TV license fee spam. These gaslighting, accusatory and threatening letters seem to verge on extortion, and are regularly received by households who do not watch any TV.

What is the worst that can happen due to ignoring these seemingly empty threats, who sends them out, what powers do they have, and is it not illegal for them to send these threatening letters groundlessly?

Comment: General advice: including opinionated language in a question ("gaslighting", "empty threats", etc) is usually not helpful.  It suggests that you have already made your mind up on the issue.  Suppose it turns out you are wrong and they are *not* empty threats.  Some people will be reluctant to write an answer saying so, because you've signaled that you would refuse to believe their answer, and would probably start an argument.  Others will delight in replying in a similarly aggressive tone, and then you really will have an argument.  It all detracts from the purpose of the site.

Comment: I think this question would be fine if phrased more neutrally: "Here is an example of a TV licensing letter.  What are the legal consequences of ignoring it?  Do any laws regulate the sending of letters such as this?"

Comment: But for the benefit of people who have not lived in the UK, please explain more about these letters.  Post an example, perhaps.

Comment: As to "who sends them out", the obvious guess would be that it's [TV Licensing](https://www.tvlicensing.co.uk/), an organization contracted to the BBC.  Do you have reason to think otherwise?  Isn't there contact info or a return address on the letter to identify the sender?

Comment: Re c1: I completely agree in principle with all you say and that there would likely be no harm in phrasing it more neutrally which is certainly in general beneficial. However I said * seemingly* empty threats, and the tone of the letters is as presumptuous one of "we know what

Comment: You did, and so do you" even though it's not at all true. This

Comment: Characterization of the c HH aracter of the LL etters could thus

Comment: Apologies mobile battery just ran out. ... Could thus very well be legally relevant to the answer, for example if that attitude in the letter makes it more within the definition of harassment by making it more reasonably likely to cause the recipient alarm or distress.

Comment: Sounds like the heart of the issue is that the messages probably come from someone not authorized to send them who is impersonating a legitimate figure much like U.S. calls allegedly from the IRS or a utility company alleging money is owed from someone impersonating those entities. Nominally this is a legal issue (people impersonating other organizations aren't allowed to demand payment allegedly due to the other organizations). But really it is a simple case of obvious fraud.

Comment: No I don't think it is fraud. TV licensing aren't claiming to be from HMRC or to be collecting taxes on HMRC behalf. But their methods and fundamental model of "enforcement" are highly controversial even while there's no impersonation.

Comment: @JosephP.: It's well established on Stack Exchange that people can vote as they please, anonymously, and calling this "cowardly" is inappropriate.  A vote is not necessarily meant as feedback to you, and it is not the obligation of every downvoter to help the post improve; it can also be a signal to the community as to whether the post is worth their time in current form.  By the way, I would point out that six people upvoted my (hopefully constructive) critical comment above.  It's possible that some of the downvoters are among them, in which case they *did* give feedback by seconding mine.

Answer (score 5):

The law doesn't work like that. You don't need a law to *allow* you to send someone a letter, just as you don't need a law to allow you to do anything at all. You are free to do anything you like unless there is a law which says you *can't* do that thing.

There is no law which specifically says that TV licensing cannot write to unlicensed properties.

More generally, there is [Section 1 of the Protection from Harassment Act 1997](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1997/40/section/1) which provides at sub-section 1:

> A person must not pursue a course of conduct — (a) which amounts to
> harassment of another, and (b) which he knows or ought to know amounts
> to harassment of the other.

Sub-section 3 provides that the above rule is not breached if "*in the particular circumstances the pursuit of the course of conduct was reasonable.*"

[Section 7](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1997/40/section/7) provides that "course of conduct" means there must be at least two occasions of that conduct, and that harassment includes alarm and distress.

It is a fast and straightforward matter to [notify TV licensing](https://www.tvlicensing.co.uk/check-if-you-need-one/topics/telling-us-you-dont-need-a-tv-licence) that you don't need a TV Licence. You are free to do that at any point before or after you receive a letter. If you do so, they will stop writing to you for two years.

It seems unlikely therefore that a court would make a finding of harassment. It is reasonable conduct for TV Licensing to write to properties which its records show are unlicensed given that they will stop doing so if you ask them to.

### "What is the worst that can happen due to ignoring these seemingly empty threats?"

If you do not do any of the following:

- Install or use a television receiver.
- Have in your possession or control a television receiver which you intend to install or use or which you know or believe someone else intends to install or use,

then you can safely ignore the letters free of consequence.

If you do any of the above then you will commit an offence under [Section 363 of the Communications Act 2003](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/21/section/363) and you can be prosecuted.

Comment: Okay but given how it does pertain to a real criminal offence, the menacing threatening and guilt-presuming attitude of the letters that are characteristic of debt collectors' tactics can certainly be said to cause harassment alarm and distress, and they are virtually undeniably designed to get people to feel like they either did something wrong or

Comment: they're required to pay rather than aiming to bring people's attention to the fact that they have an option to notify them to stop mailing them the extortionate spam. Furthermore these mailings are sent out not only to clients' known debtors but rather indiscriminately seemingly without any cause to believe that the recipients are actually

Comment: using or breaching anything at all whatsoever, yet the letters are composed to  impart an air of authority and an accompanying attitude of "guilty [of an actually existing criminal offence] until proven innocent". They are designed to make people think that one way or another authorities somewhere think them to be

Comment: in trouble and that it would probably be easier to just pay what's claimed owed than to try to clear the situation up. In a case where there's no  consumption of BBC programming, and (more relevantly) thus certainly no cause to believe that there is any consumption within a household of BBC programming these repeated threatening letters that threaten "enforcement visits to your home" can hardly be said to be reasonable and seem realistically to have as their object the causing of alarm and distress to their recipient. Do you reject much of this reasoning? (See edited post for example)

Comment: You may well be right that some of their letters use heavy handed language. But that is countered by the fact that (a) they don't start out that way but rather escalate when you ignore them, and (b) they do make it clear that you can ask them to stop. E.g. in your sample letter they wrote at the bottom "*Of course, if you don't need a licence, we'd like to stop writing to you. So please let us know at tvlicensing.co.uk/noTV.*". Note that it isn't enough that you cause alarm or distress - you also have to be acting unreasonably.

Comment: 1. The one posted was the first received. 2. The presumptuous attitude so eager and keen to treat one as guilty to me makes it utterly unreasonable. The closest comparison I can think of would be posters in a train station that aim to scare people out of fare evading. But that is to me definitely reasonable because it is being posted in a place where people go to ride the trains and due to the fact that it isn't addressed or targeted to one's home or person, I don't think it is likely to unreasonably cause alarm or distress (ie cause those to people who are innocent of the relevant offence).

Comment: But mailing letters to one's home saying things like "we have started an investigation into you" is, again, designed to cause nuisance, alarm and distress. Arguably the spam from the local takeaway doesn't even cause significant nuisance other than to a negligible degree because it's understood by everyone that it's safe to ignore, however iinm in some jurisdictions even this type of unsolicited mass commercial spam mailing is restricted or forbidden. On all of the points touched on in this comment, the TVL letters are on a completely different level, do you not see this?

Comment: It literally tries to scare you out of ignoring the letter by suggesting it will be perilous. For someone without the time to research this they may very likely determine that it would be simpler and less of a nuisance to just bite the bullet and pay rather than risk getting into "trouble" or getting the "investigation" on their "record". So my point is that its objective is to cause a nuisance, and its strategy for effectively causing a nuisance appears to be through perpetrating deliberately alarming and distressful harassment (repeated communication).

Comment: Sure, it does give a (much less prominent) note in what can relatively be called fine print that one has the option of informing them one is not liable. But to me, for the reasons mentioned, that is well counterweighted by the more prominent intimidation tactics used.